# visual C++ string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, subscript

I am stuck with the error "string subscript out of range". 
After testing, I am pretty sure that it's because of this function, which is used for reading values in a file, but have no idea what's wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string read(string value) {
    ifstream input;
    string line="", output="";
    size_t pos;
    bool a = true;
    int i = 0;
    input.open("pg_options.txt");
    if (!input.is_open()) {
        cout << "pg_options.txt missing.";
        return "error";
    }
    while (getline(input, line)) { //get file lines
        pos = line.find(value);
        if (pos == string::npos) { //if value in line
            while (a == true) {
                if (line[i] == '=') { //after "=" 
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            for (i; line[i] != ' '; i++) {
                output += line[i]; //put value to output
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    return output;
}
```

pg_options.txt:

```
include_special_characters=true
include_upper_case=true
include_lower_case=true
include_numbers=true
digits=10
```

`cout << read("digits")` returns the error mentioned above.

Comment: `if (pos == string::npos)`. Did you mean: `if (pos != string::npos)` by any chance? The former checks whether `value` is not found inside `line` while the latter checks if `value` is found inside `line`.

Comment: It would be best to put together a [mcve]. One thing that I noticed is that the comment on this line: `if (pos == string::npos) { //if value in line` is exactly the opposite of the code. Maybe you meant to use `!=` there? `for (i; line[i] != ' '; i++)` is also odd. You don't need the first `i` in there, it does nothing, and none fo your strings seem to have a space in them so this will definitely go past the end of the string. I suggest you run this in a debugger and when you get the error go up the call stack to find your code and see where it went wrong.

Comment: `a` does not change in the inner `while` loop, so if you enter this loop once, you remain in the loop forever unless you encounter a `=` (or until the program crashes with the error you've encountered). Btw: I'd recommend making `value` const and probably even a reference; modifying it accidentally would result in unexpected behavior and making it a const ref means in some scenarios you may prevent an unnecessary copy of the array backing the string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. I solved this by editing the `for` loop:

```
string read(string value) {
    ifstream input;
    int olength;
    string line = "", output = "";
    size_t pos;
    bool a = true;
    int i = 0;
    input.open("pg_options.txt");
    if (!input.is_open()) {
        cout << "pg_options.txt missing.";
        return "error";
    }
    while (getline(input, line)) {
        pos = line.find(value);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            while (a == true) {
                if (line[i] == '=') {
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            olength = line.length() - value.length() - 1;
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < olength; i2++) {
                output += line[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    return output;
}
```